# Remove quotes sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a file with thousands of records pipe delimited with each field enclosed by quotes. I basically need to read the line and write the line with the quotes removed to a new file.
What is the correct sed command to get this to run correctly?  I installed sed on my windows machine but i keep

[input]

```
"First Name"|"Last Name"|"address"|"City"|"State"|"Zip"
```

[output]

```
First Name|Last Name|address|City|State|Zip
```

Commands that i have tried separately but neither of them work

```
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>sed 's/\"//g' "C:\Users\abc\Documents\testFile.txt" > quoteOutput.txt

C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>sed s/\"//g "C:\Users\abc\Documents\testFile.txt" > quoteOutput.txt"
```

Comment: All the arcane Windows quoting nonsense will cripple you. Just install cygwin and then you can use sed, tr, awk, whatever without losing your sanity.

Comment: @EdMorton Or just use a *nix OS :)

Answer (score 2):

```
% echo '"First Name"|"Last Name"|"address"|"City"|"State"|"Zip"' | sed -e 's/"//g'                                                                        

First Name|Last Name|address|City|State|Zip
```

You needn't escape the `"` unless its a delimiter.

[EDIT to show how to run it under Windows]

```
echo 's/"//g' > c:\Users\abc\Documents\test.sed'
sed -f c:\Users\abc\Documents\test.sed C:\Users\abc\Documents\quoteFile.txt > "C:\Users\abc\Documents\quoteFileProcessed.txt"
```

Comment: based on the question, he's running this at a windows command prompt, where single quotes have no special meaning

Comment: That's exactly what he needs to do, surround his script in quotes so he **can** run it without getting into escaping issues

Comment: I tried to run the following command and got an error on windows:

C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>sed -e 's/"//g' "C:\Users\abc\Documents\testFile.txt" > "C:\Users\abc\quotesRemoved.txt"

[output]
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: Ok, try putting 's/"//g' into a file and passing said file in as the `-f` parameter to [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/‎)

Comment: I add the line 's/"//g' as the first line of the data file and it didn't work.

Comment: Paste the complete command you're running in the next comment?

Comment: the command that i run in windows prompt was:

C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>sed -f "C:\Users\abc\Documents\quoteFile.txt" > "C:\Users\abc\Documents\quoteFileProcessed.txt


In the file first line i had:
's/"//g'

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option would be to use `tr` (assuming it's included in the toolkit you have installed):

```
tr -d \" < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Think better is to quote the double quote symbol inside sed command list using backslash:

```
C:\tmp>cat input
"First Name"|"Last Name"|"address"|"City"|"State"|"Zip"

C:\tmp>sed "s/\"//g" input
First Name|Last Name|address|City|State|Zip
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution for Windows?
Piping and outputting seems to work again without errors, using the escape char hat (^):

```
cat input | tr -d \^" > output
```